# Can we use two different methods to read a file in a same block of code?

Tags: while-loop, count, scanf, readfile, getc

// **Method I`m using to read words,Characters,whitespaces,new lines from a file..**
// **But when i run it only the upper while gets executed and if i place the below whileloop first,**
//**only that gets executed. In short only one while loop gets executed.**
// *How can i address it??*

````
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h> 
int count_items(FILE *f);
// MAIN CODE
int main()
{ 
    printf("-------Programm to count_items in a file-------\n");

    FILE *f = fopen("sample.txt","r");

    count_items(f);

    fclose(f);

    return 0; 
} 

//FUNCTION TO COUNT NUMBER OF ITEMS IN A FILE

int count_items(FILE *f)
{
    int word_count,line_count,white_count,char_count;
    char sbuff[100],cbuff;

    // **Method I`m using to read characters from a file..**

    while((cbuff=getc(f))!=EOF)
    {
        char_count++;

        if(cbuff=='\n')
        {
            line_count++;
        }
        if(cbuff==' ')
        {
            white_count++;
            
        }

    } 

    while(fscanf(f,"%s",sbuff)==1)
    {
        word_count++;
    }

    // PRINT THE RESULT
    printf("The number of words in file are %d\n\n",word_count );
    printf("The number of characters in file are %d\n\n",char_count );
    printf("The number of whitespaces in file are %d\n\n",white_count );
    printf("The number of lines in file are %d\n\n",line_count );

    return 0;
} ```

// **IT SEEMS THAT I NEED TO FLUSH THE BUFFER BEFORE GOING TO SECOND WHILE LOOP. IF SO , HOW DO I DO THAT?**
````

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because that next loop is trying to read from the file whilst the current position is at the end of that file. You need to set current position from the beginning, e.g.

```
fseek(f, SEEK_SET, 0);
```

See [fseek](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fseek) spec for more details.

Comment: Thanks man, it worked . This buffer problem is a real neck pain in C. Not the case with Python